# How to access values of a sets that is inside another sets

Tags: python, for-loop, set

So I have a Set that is inside another set as below:

```
country = { 
       'spain': { 'capital':'madrid', 'population':46.77 },
       'france': { 'capital':'paris', 'population':66.03 },
       'germany': { 'capital':'berlin', 'population':80.62 },
       'norway': { 'capital':'oslo', 'population':5.084 },
       'peru' : {'capital':'lima', 'population':250}
     }
```

I needed to display the name of each of the capital city per country so I decided to use a for loop.

```
for countries in country:
    print('capital city of '+countries+' is '+countries)
```

Now I was able to access each of the country but not the capital city. I have tried adding some variable between the for loop since it gives me a 'too much to pack error'. My second attempts below.

```
for countries,value in country.items():
    print('capital city of '+countries+' is '+countries[value])
```

Anyway i can overpass this one?

Comment: You would have a better question if, for each code attempt you had also listed its output, whether that is an error traceback or results of `print()` statements.

Comment: Alright, I'll put the error statement for each of the attempts I made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the `country` dict and print the appropriate capital using the value `key`:

```
country = { 
       'spain': { 'capital':'madrid', 'population':46.77 },
       'france': { 'capital':'paris', 'population':66.03 },
       'germany': { 'capital':'berlin', 'population':80.62 },
       'norway': { 'capital':'oslo', 'population':5.084 },
       'peru' : {'capital':'lima', 'population':250}
     }
     

for country, capitals in country.items():
    print("Country: {0}, Capital: {1}".format(country, capitals['capital']))
```

OUTPUT:

```
Country: peru, Capital: lima                                                                                                                                                 
Country: germany, Capital: berlin                                                                                                                                            
Country: spain, Capital: madrid                                                                                                                                              
Country: france, Capital: paris                                                                                                                                              
Country: norway, Capital: oslo
```

**EDIT**:

one-liner:

```
print([{"Country: {0}, Capital: {1}".format(cn, cp['capital'])} for cn, cp in country.items()])
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{'Country: spain, Capital: madrid'}, {'Country: germany, Capital: berlin'}, {'Country: norway, Capital: oslo'}, {'Country: france, Capital: paris'}, {'Country: peru, Capita
l: lima'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

btw you have nested `dict`s. You don't have any `set`s.

Did you mean this:

```py
for name,value in country.items():
    print(f'capital city of {name} is {value["capital"]}')
```

Output:

```
capital city of spain is madrid
capital city of france is paris
capital city of germany is berlin
capital city of norway is oslo
capital city of peru is lima
```

*Update:* I have used an `f-string` in the `print()` statement which is sometimes an easier way to format strings.